# replace escape character in flex

Tags: flex-lexer

I use flex to work on a scanner to replace `\"` with `"`; and `\\` with `\`.

so my code is like

```
%%
\\"    \";
\\\    \\;
```

but when I compile, I get an error message like `missing quote`.
I think it's the right regular expression, did I get wrong or it's something special with flex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape both the `\` AND `"` character. In order to match `\"` you use `\\\"` not `\\"`. To match `\\` you use `\\\\` not `\\\`.

Another thing is that flex matches a regexp and then execute the C code you placed in the associated action. Your example doesn't look like correct flex statements.

Answer (score 3):

to match `*`,`[`,`]`,`(`,`)`,`"` ,`\`,`{`,`}`in flex, you have to use escape character(not needed for single quote character).